# python code for "gcloud beta compute instances update-container"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I need to update a GCP vm instance that runs a Docker image. I found the "gcloud beta compute instances update-container" command can do that. However, if i need to run it via cloud function, then gcloud command will not work. I'm wondering if there's equal python library which can do the same thing for me?

Comment: Maybe there is something but what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried running "gcloud beta compute instances update-container"  using python script on cloud function, and it failed because the gcloud does not exist

Comment: You see that error because you can't run gclouds command in Cloud Functions environment.

Comment: @DenisT. yes i understand that. It looks like we can't/shouldn't install Cloud SDK in cloud function either. That's why i asked if there's any python client library I could use. I checked the Compute Engine API but didn't find available methods for that.

Comment: Please see the answer I've posted in this thread - I have created a feature request for you asking to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the Compute Engine API - Beta and unfortunately there is no API for `update-container`

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1) doesn't seem to have a method for updating VMs running container images yet.

I have opened a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173608979) asking to implement this functionality. I'd recommend you to star it to be notified once there is an update.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to update the container VM without using the gcloud command. There's setMetadata method under the compute engine API: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMetadata
This can be used to update your VM's metadata.

Comment: what do you set at metadata?